# Getting data from another query into my query

Tags: mysql, subquery

this is my very first post. I´ve been browsing through this site several times searching for tips and help. The job I have right now requires that I get some information from a database, which I have to do through MySQL. Though I did some database programing way back then (dBase, Clipper) and I might get the idea of what I am trying to accomplish, getting used to SQL and getting data from the database and tables still puzzles me.

Going to the question, I actually have 2 right now. The database I am working with does not have a stock figure for any given product, but you have to calculate the stock based on the movements logged in another table (stockmovements). I´ve managed to write the code for a small query that properly returns the stock.

Now the 2 questions I have are:
1. How can I filter the result of that query so I would only get those products for which stock is more than 0 (right now I get all the products and it´s stock)?
2. I need to prepare a query where I get the orders that are pending and the stock I have for any said product on that pending order. I have both queries. One that gives me the orders, with all the products I am missing to ship. And the onw I said before that calculates the stock. The question is, how do I use the stock info to add the stock to the pending orders?

Any help would be really appreciatted. I was reading about making a subquery or something of the sort, but I don´t know how to do it.

This is the CODE I am using to get the info on the open orders.
What I need to add is the stock of each product.

```
SELECT
  `pedidos`.`Numero` AS `Orden de venta`,
  `empresas`.`Empresa` AS `Empresa`,
  `pedidos`.`NroOrden` AS `Orden de compra`,
  `pedidos`.`FechaEntrega` AS `Fecha Entrega`,
  `pedidositems`.`Codigo` AS `Codigo`,
  `pedidositems`.`Descripcion` AS `Descripcion`,
  `pedidositems`.`Cantidad` AS `Cantidad`,
  (
    CASE `pedidositems`.`Estado` WHEN 0 THEN "Pendiente"
    WHEN 1 THEN "Entregado" END
  ) AS "Estado"


FROM
  `pedidos`
  INNER JOIN `pedidositems` ON `pedidos`.`RecID` = `pedidositems`.`IDPedido`
  INNER JOIN `productos` ON `productos`.`RecID` = `pedidositems`.`IDProducto`
  INNER JOIN `contactos` ON `contactos`.`IDContacto` = `pedidos`.`IDRef`
  INNER JOIN `empresas` ON `empresas`.`IDEmpresa` = `contactos`.`IDEmpresa`
WHERE
  `pedidos`.`Estado` = 0
```

To calculate the STOCK, I need to browse the stock_movements on table productosstockmovimientos. I have this query below that calculates stock for each and every product.

```
SELECT
  `productos`.`Codigo`,
  `productos`.`Descripcion`,
  `productosstockmovimientos`.`Cantidad`,
   Sum(
     `productosstockmovimientos`.`Cantidad` *
     productosstockmovimientos.equivalencia *
     (
       CASE productosstockmovimientos.tipo when 0 then 1 when 1
       then -1 else 0 end
     )
   ) AS `STOCK` 

FROM
  `productos`
  INNER JOIN `productosstockmovimientos` ON `productos`.`RecID` =
    `productosstockmovimientos`.`IDProducto`

GROUP BY
  `productos`.`Codigo`
```

Comment: Please add to your question a data sample and the expected result. A few rows of data will greatly help us to understand what you need.

Comment: show us the code you are using , a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..  as tabular text  (not image )

Comment: scaisEdge, how do I add tabular text? I´ve tried to copy from an Excel chart but it would paste as an image.

Comment: I have added the code I am using